# Construct an example of $C^\infty$ vector-valued function $\mathbf{a}(t)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometry, analysis, differential-geometry

I want to construct an example of $C^\infty$ vector-valued function $\mathbf{a}(t)$ satisfying:

1.$\mathbf{a}(t)\times\mathbf{a}'(t)=\mathbf{0}$ identically

2.$\mathbf{a}'(t)\ne\mathbf{0}$ everywhere

3.$\mathbf{a}(t_n)=\mathbf{0}$ for some sequence $t_n\rightarrow0$ decreasingly

4.$\mathbf{a}(t)$ changes its direction from $t<0$ to $t>0$

It might cause confusion to say "the direction of $\mathbf{a}(t)$". Here I mean the direction of the vector $\mathbf{a}(t)$ itself, not the direction of $\mathbf{a}'(t)$.

I tried to use the "mollifier" $e^{-1/t^2}$ to construct some $\mathbf{a}(t)$ satisfying one or two of them, but I didn't succeed in keeping those three conditions hold simultaneously.

I wonder if there is an example. I'm not very good at constructing "counterexamples".

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is $\times$ the cross product or the scalar product? If the former, take $a(t)=t v $ where v is a constant vector. If the latter,  compute $\frac{d}{dt} |a|^2$.

Comment: @Bananach It's the cross product.

Comment: Ignore my first comment.  I misread condition 3

Comment: The first condition tells you that the motion is along a line, so we may as well just do this on $\Bbb R$. It seems to me that Rolle's Theorem says that if 3) happens, then 2) cannot.

Comment: @tedshifrin I'm not very sure about this... Rolle's theorem fails in $\mathbf{R}^3$ after all... Could you make it more specific?

Comment: Remember that 1) tells us that $\mathbf a(t)=f(t)\mathbf c$ for some fixed vector $\mathbf c$ and scalar function $f(t)$.

Comment: @tedshifrin I can take it intrinsically. But I still want a strict proof. Would you mind writting it out for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be no such animal $\mathbf a(t)$. Here's a sketch of the argument.

By (1) and (3), the motion occurs along a line. Because $\mathbf a'$ is a *nonzero* scalar multiple of $\mathbf a$, the particle cannot change direction. To see this rigorously, let $\mathbf a(t) = \lambda(t)\mathbf b(t)$ with $\|\mathbf b(t)\|=1$ and $\lambda(t)\ne 0$. It is standard that this condition means that $\mathbf b(t)\cdot \mathbf b'(t)=0$. Differentiating, we get $\mathbf a'(t) = \lambda'(t)\mathbf b(t)+\lambda(t)\mathbf b'(t)$. Dotting with $\mathbf b'(t)$ and using the fact that $\mathbf a'$ is a multiple of $\mathbf b$, we get $0=\mathbf a'(t)\cdot\mathbf b'(t) = \lambda(t)\|\mathbf b'(t)\|^2$. So $\mathbf b$ is constant.

Now write $\mathbf a(t)=f(t)\mathbf b$. By (2), $f'(t)$ is nowhere zero, hence, say, everywhere positive. This means that $\mathbf a(t)=\mathbf 0$ for at most one value of $t$, contradicting (3).

Comment: This proof is very clear. Thank you very much. :-D

Comment: Sorry to bother again... Let's just ignore (3) for a simpler discussion... When I follow your approach to prove it myself, I stuck in this point: How do we derive "$\mathbf a(t) = \lambda(t)\mathbf b(t)$ with $\|\mathbf b(t)\|=1$" from (1)&(2)? It seems to me that I should go to solve an ODE system. By only assumption that $\mathbf a'(t)\ne \mathbf 0$, I can't pass this gap. Could you give me some instructions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I need to post another question to ask for the detail. If necessary, tell me please.

Comment: @gžd15: You're right, of course. We need to use $\mathbf a(t)\ne 0$ to even have a unit vector $\mathbf b(t)$. One could allow the particle to come in to $\mathbf 0$, stopping there, and then leave in a different direction. You can do this smoothly with the usual mollifier trick to which you referred. But if you require $\mathbf a'\ne \mathbf 0$ at such a moment, my proof is correct.